# Hibernate MappingException: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'Agency'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application using Hibernate for ORM, and I'm facing an issue with the entity mappings. When I try to run my application, it throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.intelligentadmindashboard.intelligentadmindashboard.domain.Agency' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.intelligentadmindashboard.intelligentadmindashboard.domain.Agency' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.intelligentadmindashboard.intelligentadmindashboard.domain.Agency' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
```

The issue seems to be related to the Agency entity, which is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tr_agency")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Agency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)

    private long id;

    @Column(name="label")
    private String label;

    @Column(name="leave_balance")
    private Double leave_balance;

    private LocalDateTime deleted_at;

    private String code;

    @Column(name="has_previous_year_holidays")
    private Boolean has_previous_year_holidays;

    @Embedded
    private Country country;


}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="collaborator")
public class Collaborator {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
//other fields 


    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Agency.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="agency_id",referencedColumnName = "id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private  Agency agency;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ServiceType.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="service_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ServiceType serviceType;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Departement.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="departement_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Departement departement;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = StatutProfessional.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="statut_professionnel_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private StatutProfessional statutProfessional;

}
```

I don't where is the problem exactly

Comment: You are embedding `Country`. Does this also have an ID field? (It should not ...)

Answer (score -1):

In your Agency entity comment this line

```
@Column(name="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```